# Algorithm to find disconnected nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm looking for a way, given a directed graph, to find all nodes that are not reachable from a given starting point.  I've got an idea, based on a similar concept to Dijkstra's Algorithm, that goes like this (pseudocode), but is there a better way?

```
function DisconnectedNodes(Graph, Start)
  var Unknown = new list
  var Open = new list
  var Closed = new list
  for each Node in Graph
    Unknown.add(Node)
  Open.StealFrom(Unknown, Start)
  while Open.Count > 0
    var Current = Open[0]
    for each Node in Current.Destinations
      if Node in Unknown
         Open.StealFrom(Unknown, Node)
    Closed.StealFrom(Open, Current)
  return Unknown
```

Answer (score 5):

Just run a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from the starting node! All the nodes not visited after the BFS cannot be reached from your starting point.

Comment: The algorithm described there looks essentially like the one I gave, except that it has a "destination" node and an implicit root of the graph.

Comment: Yes. I didn't noticed that, it's a bit hairy. What does *StealFrom* do? Also, it's a well know algorithm, and quite the standard for your task. May I ask why do you need for another approach?

Comment: It moves an item from one list to another.  And I don't "need another approach," I'm just trying to figure out how it should work. Graph theory has never really been my strong point.